# How to link Google form respond to existing Google sheet?

Tags: database, google-sheets, google-forms

[My Existing Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehfu6.png)

[image: My Existing Database]

I already have an existing database in a spreadsheet. The database will need to update over time. I want to make data input easier so I make a Google form to fill it in. But, every time I want to check the Google form responses it keeps making a new sheet and not populate in the same sheet of an existing database.

I tried to link the spreadsheet to Google form, but the responses keep showing in the new sheet, not in the same sheet. What should I do to make it show in the same sheet as an existing database? I want it to update automatically and easier data input. I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: did you ever find a workable solution? I am also trying to find a way to use a form to make the input easier.

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking is not possible. this issue is mostly solved on the 3rd sheet where you use simple query formula to join your existing database and form responses. something like:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:Z; FormResponses1!A:Z}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```